# Bootstrap Table conditional show/hide columns

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf, bootstrap-table

I need to show/hide columns in my bootstrap table. If a condition is true I want to show some colums and hidding some others. 
I tried various methods, without success

I use `thymeleaf` for my views.

This is my html page code:

**MY TABLE**:

```
    <table data-toggle="table" 
        th:data-url="@{/certificato/list/{idCommessa}(idCommessa=${commessa.id})}"
        data-pagination="true" 
        data-search="true" 
        data-classes="table table-hover" 
        data-striped="true" id="tableCertificato"
        data-side-pagination="client">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th data-sortable="true" data-field="numeroCertificato" th:text="#{numeroCertificato}"></th>
              <th data-sortable="true" data-field="dataCertificato" th:text="#{dataCertificato}" data-formatter="dateFormatter"></th>
              <th data-field="nFabbrica" th:text="#{nFabbrica}" ></th>
              <th data-field="modulo" th:text="#{modulo}" ></th>
              <th data-field="categoriaRischio" th:text="#{categoriaRischio}"></th>

     </thead>
```

**My JS:**

```
    $(function(){
             var tipoCertVar = [[${commessa.tipoAttivita}]];
        if(tipoCertVar == 'TPED'){
             $('#tableCertificato').bootstrapTable('hideColumn', 'nFabbrica');
             $('#tableCertificato').bootstrapTable('hideColumn', 'modulo');
             $('#tableCertificato').bootstrapTable('hideColumn', 'categoriaRischio');
         }else{
             $('#tableCertificato').bootstrapTable('showColumn', 'nFabbrica');
             $('#tableCertificato').bootstrapTable('showColumn', 'modulo');
             $('#tableCertificato').bootstrapTable('showColumn', 'categoriaRischio');

        });
```

The condition is true, I debugged it with an alert message.
But the hide/show column not run. The columns are always shown.

I try to change my code without success so:

```
<th th:if="${commessa.tipoAttivita != 'TPED' }" data-field="nFabbrica" th:text="#{nFabbrica}"></th>
```

and using a conditional `data-visible`. 
Same results.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I had resolved with this step:

1. set `data-visible="false"` for all the conditional columns of your table;
2. change your javascript insert this var: `$table = $('#tableCertificato').bootstrapTable({ });` and use this in your if-statement:

   ```
        $table = $('#tableCertificato').bootstrapTable({ });

       if(tipoCertVar != 'TPED')   {
           $table.bootstrapTable('showColumn', 'nFabbrica');
           $table.bootstrapTable('showColumn', 'modulo');
           $table.bootstrapTable('showColumn', 'categoriaRischio');
       }
   ```

I hope this solution will help you.

Comment: Thanks, it's run for me!